# Assembly x86 - what's wrong with my code

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

For some reason which I can't figure it out because everything seems right, normal and logic, when I launch my code it does this:
[image: My program:]

Here is my code:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
x dw 20h
y dw 20h

red db 4 
white db 0Fh

a dw 20h
b dw 20h

c dw 20h
d dw 40h

e dw 20h
f dw 60h

q dw 20h
r dw 80h        

g dw 20h
h dw 0A0h

i dw 20h
j dw 20h

k dw 40h
l dw 20h

m dw 60h
n dw 20h

o dw 0A0h
p dw 20h

s dw 80h
t dw 20h

u dw 20h
v dw 20h
w dw 20h

inst1 db 'Press: 1,2,3 or 4 to drop a disc.',13,10,'$'
inst2 db 'To win the game align 4 discs.',13,10,'$'

player1discstring db 'Player 1 Disc:',13,10,'$'
player1disccolor db 0Eh
p1x dw 127h
p1y dw 24h

player2discstring db 'Player 2 Disc:',13,10,'$'
player2disccolor db 1h
p2x dw 127h
p2y dw 39h

FirstColumnArray db 4 dup(0)
SecondColumnArray db 4 dup(0)
ThirdColumnArray db 4 dup(0)
FourthColumnArray db 4 dup(0)

Player1Turn dw 255

Player1Drawx dw 0h  
Player1Drawy dw 0h

Player2Drawx dw 0h
Player2Drawy dw 0h

Player1Winner db 'Player 1 Won!',13,10,'$'
Player2Winner db 'Player 2 Won!',13,10,'$' 

CODESEG
start:
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

; Graphic mode
mov ax, 13h
int 10h

RedDotLoop:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[x]
    mov dx,[y]
    mov al,[red]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [x]
    cmp cx, 0A0h
    jl RedDotLoop

Square:
    mov bh, 0h
    inc [y]
    mov [x], 20h
    cmp dx, 0A0h
    jl RedDotLoop

WhiteHorizontalDotLoop1:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[a]
    mov dx,[b]
    mov al,[white]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [a]
    cmp cx, 0A0h
    jl WhiteHorizontalDotLoop1

WhiteHorizontalDotLoop2:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[c]
    mov dx,[d]
    mov al,[white]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [c]
    cmp cx, 0A0h
    jl WhiteHorizontalDotLoop2

WhiteHorizontalDotLoop3:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[e]
    mov dx,[f]
    mov al,[white]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [e]
    cmp cx, 0A0h
    jl WhiteHorizontalDotLoop3

WhiteHorizontalDotLoop4:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[g]
    mov dx,[h]
    mov al,[white]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [g]
    cmp cx, 0A0h
    jl WhiteHorizontalDotLoop4

WhiteHorizontalDotLoop5:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[q]
    mov dx,[r]
    mov al,[white]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [q]
    cmp cx, 0A0h
    jl WhiteHorizontalDotLoop5

WhiteVerticalDotLoop1:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[i]
    mov dx,[j]
    mov al,[white]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [j]
    cmp dx, 0A0h
    jl WhiteVerticalDotLoop1

WhiteVerticalDotLoop2:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[k]
    mov dx,[l]
    mov al,[white]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [l]
    cmp dx, 0A0h
    jl WhiteVerticalDotLoop2

WhiteVerticalDotLoop3:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[m]
    mov dx,[n]
    mov al,[white]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [n]
    cmp dx, 0A0h
    jl WhiteVerticalDotLoop3

WhiteVerticalDotLoop4:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[o]
    mov dx,[p]
    mov al,[white]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [p]
    cmp dx, 0A0h
    jl WhiteVerticalDotLoop4

WhiteVerticalDotLoop5:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[s]
    mov dx,[t]
    mov al,[white]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [t]
    cmp dx, 0A0h
    jl WhiteVerticalDotLoop5

Write1Loop:
    mov dl, ''
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    inc [u]
    cmp [u], 75h
    jl Write1Loop
    mov dl, '1'
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h

Write2Loop:
    mov dl, ''
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    inc [v]
    cmp [v], 24h
    jl Write2Loop
    mov dl, '2'
    mov ah, 2   
    int 21h 

Write3Loop:
    mov dl, ''
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    inc [w]
    cmp [w], 23h
    jl Write3Loop
    mov dl, '3'
    mov ah, 2   
    int 21h 

Write4Loop:
    mov dl, ''
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    inc [w]
    cmp [w], 26h
    jl Write4Loop
    mov dl, '4'
    mov ah, 2   
    int 21h

Instructions1:
    mov dl, 0   
    mov dh, 21    
    mov ah, 2     
    mov bh, 0     
    int 10h       
    lea dx, [inst1]
    mov dx, offset inst1
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

Instructions2:
    mov dl, 0 
    mov dh, 23    
    mov ah, 2     
    mov bh, 0     
    int 10h       
    lea dx, [inst2]
    mov dx, offset inst2
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

PlayerOneDisc:
    mov es, ax
    mov ah, 13h
    mov bl, [player1disccolor]
    mov dl, 22   
    mov dh, 5  
    mov ah, 2     
    mov bh, 0     
    int 10h
    lea dx, [player1discstring]
    mov dx, offset player1discstring
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

PlayerTwoDisc:
    mov dl, 22   
    mov dh, 8  
    mov ah, 2     
    mov bh, 0     
    int 10h       
    lea dx, [player2discstring]
    mov dx, offset player2discstring
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h

Player1Disc:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[p1x]
    mov dx,[p1y]
    mov al,[player1disccolor]
    mov ah, 0ch
    int 10h
    inc [p1x]
    cmp cx, 135h
    jl Player1Disc

Player1Square:
    mov bh, 0h
    inc [p1y]
    mov [p1x], 127h
    cmp dx, 32h
    jl Player1Disc

Player2Disc:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[p2x]
    mov dx,[p2y]
    mov al,[player2disccolor]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [p2x]
    cmp cx, 135h
    jl Player2Disc

Player2Square:
    mov bh, 0h
    inc [p2y]
    mov [p2x], 127h
    cmp dx , 47h
    jl Player2Disc

proc CheckIfPlayer1Won
    Row1:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 1
    je Continue1Row1
    jmp Row2    
    Continue1Row1:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray], 1
    je Continue2Row1
    jmp Row2    
    Continue2Row1:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray], 1
    je Continue3Row1
    jmp Row2
    Continue3Row1:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Row2

    Row2:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue1Row2
    jmp Row3
    Continue1Row2:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue2Row2
    jmp Row3
    Continue2Row2:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue3Row2
    jmp Row3
    Continue3Row2:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Row3

    Row3:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue1Row3
    jmp Row4
    Continue1Row3:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue2Row2
    jmp Row4
    Continue2Row3:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue3Row2
    jmp Row4
    Continue3Row3:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Row4

    Row4:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Continue1Row4
    jmp Column1
    Continue1Row4:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Continue2Row4
    jmp Column1
    Continue2Row4:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Continue3Row4
    jmp Column1
    Continue3Row4:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Column1

    Player1WinnerAnnounce1:
    mov dl, 22
    mov dh, 12
    mov ah, 2
    mov bh, 0
    int 10h
    lea dx, [Player1Winner]
    mov dx, offset Player1Winner
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 
    jmp exit

    Column1:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 1
    je Continue1Column1
    jmp Column2
    Continue1Column1:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue2Column1
    jmp Column2
    Continue2Column1:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue3Column1
    jmp Column2
    Continue3Column1:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp Column2

    Column2:    
    cmp [SecondColumnArray], 1
    je Continue1Column2
    jmp Column3
    Continue1Column2:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue2Column2
    jmp Column3
    Continue2Column2:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue3Column2
    jmp Column3
    Continue3Column2:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp Column3

    Column3:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray], 1
    je Continue1Column3
    jmp Column4
    Continue1Column3:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue2Column3
    jmp Column4
    Continue2Column3:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue3Column3
    jmp Column4
    Continue3Column3:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp Column4

    Column4:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 1
    je Continue1Column4
    jmp DiagnolLine1
    Continue1Column4:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue2Column4
    jmp DiagnolLine1
    Continue2Column4:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue3Column4
    jmp DiagnolLine1
    Continue3Column4:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp DiagnolLine1

    Player1WinnerAnnounce2:
    mov dl, 22
    mov dh, 12
    mov ah, 2
    mov bh, 0
    int 10h
    lea dx, [Player1Winner]
    mov dx, offset Player1Winner
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 
    jmp exit    

    DiagnolLine1:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 1
    je Continue1DiagnolLine1
    jmp DiagnolLine2
    Continue1DiagnolLine1:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue2DiagnolLine1
    jmp DiagnolLine2
    Continue2DiagnolLine1:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue3DiagnolLine1
    jmp DiagnolLine2
    Continue3DiagnolLine1:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce3
    jmp DiagnolLine2

    DiagnolLine2:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 1
    je Continue1DiagnolLine2
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
    Continue1DiagnolLine2:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 1
    je Continue2DiagnolLine2
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
    Continue2DiagnolLine2:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 1
    je Continue3DiagnolLine2
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
    Continue3DiagnolLine2:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 1
    je Player1WinnerAnnounce3
    jmp CheckIfPlayer2Won

Player1WinnerAnnounce3:
    mov dl, 22
    mov dh, 12
    mov ah, 2
    mov bh, 0
    int 10h
    lea dx, [Player1Winner]
    mov dx, offset Player1Winner
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 
    jmp exit

    ret
endp CheckIfPlayer1Won

proc CheckIfPlayer2Won
    Row1T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 2
    je Continue1Row1T
    jmp Row2T
    Continue1Row1T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray], 2
    je Continue2Row1T
    jmp Row2T
    Continue2Row1T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray], 2
    je Continue3Row1T
    jmp Row2T
    Continue3Row1T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Row2T

    Row2T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue1Row2T
    jmp Row3T
    Continue1Row2T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue2Row2T
    jmp Row3T
    Continue2Row2T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue3Row2T
    jmp Row3T
    Continue3Row2T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Row3T

    Row3T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue1Row3T
    jmp Row4T
    Continue1Row3T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue2Row3T
    jmp Row4T
    Continue2Row3T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue3Row3T
    jmp Row4T
    Continue3Row3T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Row4T

    Row4T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Continue1Row4T
    jmp Column1T
    Continue1Row4T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Continue2Row4T
    jmp Column1T
    Continue2Row4T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Continue3Row4T
    jmp Column1T
    Continue3Row4T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce1
    jmp Column1T

    Player2WinnerAnnounce1:
    mov dl, 22
    mov dh, 12
    mov ah, 2
    mov bh, 0
    int 10h
    lea dx, [Player2Winner]
    mov dx, offset Player2Winner
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 
    jmp exit

    Column1T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 2
    je Continue1Column1T
    jmp Column2T
    Continue1Column1T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue2Column1T
    jmp Column2T
    Continue2Column1T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue3Column1T
    jmp Column2T
    Continue3Column1T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp Column2T

    Column2T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray], 2
    je Continue1Column2T
    jmp Column3T
    Continue1Column2T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue2Column2T
    jmp Column3T
    Continue2Column2T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue3Column2T
    jmp Column3T
    Continue3Column2T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp Column3T

    Column3T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray], 2
    je Continue1Column3T
    jmp Column4T
    Continue1Column3T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue2Column3T
    jmp Column4T
    Continue2Column3T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue3Column3T
    jmp Column4T
    Continue3Column3T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp Column4T

    Column4T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 2
    je Continue1Column4T
    jmp DiagnolLine1T
    Continue1Column4T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue2Column4T
    jmp DiagnolLine1T
    Continue2Column4T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue3Column4T
    jmp DiagnolLine1T
    Continue3Column4T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce2
    jmp DiagnolLine1T

    Player2WinnerAnnounce2:
    mov dl, 22
    mov dh, 12
    mov ah, 2
    mov bh, 0
    int 10h
    lea dx, [Player2Winner]
    mov dx, offset Player2Winner
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 
    jmp exit

    DiagnolLine1T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 2
    je Continue1DiagnolLine1T
    jmp DiagnolLine2T
    Continue1DiagnolLine1T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue2DiagnolLine1T
    jmp DiagnolLine2T
    Continue2DiagnolLine1T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue3DiagnolLine1T
    jmp DiagnolLine2T
    Continue3DiagnolLine1T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce3
    jmp DiagnolLine2T

    DiagnolLine2T:
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 2
    je Continue1DiagnolLine2T
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
    Continue1DiagnolLine2T:
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 2
    je Continue2DiagnolLine2T
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
    Continue2DiagnolLine2T:
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 2
    je Continue3DiagnolLine2T
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
    Continue3DiagnolLine2T:
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 2
    je Player2WinnerAnnounce3
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number

    Player2WinnerAnnounce3:
    mov dl, 22
    mov dh, 12
    mov ah, 2
    mov bh, 0
    int 10h
    lea dx, [Player2Winner]
    mov dx, offset Player2Winner
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 
    jmp exit

    ret
endp CheckIfPlayer2Won

proc CheckPlayer1Number
    mov ah, 7
    int 21h
    cmp al, 31h
    je CheckColumn1
    cmp al, 32h
    je CheckColumn2
    cmp al, 33h
    je MoveToCheckColumn3
    cmp al, 34h
    je MoveToCheckColumn4
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
endp CheckPlayer1Number

proc CheckColumn1
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 0
    je ChangeColumn1Number1 
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 1], 0
    je ChangeColumn1Number2 
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 2], 0
    je ChangeColumn1Number3 
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 0
    je ChangeColumn1Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
endp CheckColumn1

proc ChangeColumn1Number1
    inc [FirstColumnArray]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 87h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn1Number1

proc ChangeColumn1Number2
    inc [FirstColumnArray + 1]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn1Number2

proc ChangeColumn1Number3
    inc [FirstColumnArray + 2]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn1Number3

proc ChangeColumn1Number4
    inc [FirstColumnArray + 3]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 27h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn1Number4

proc MoveToCheckColumn3
    jmp CheckColumn3
endp MoveToCheckColumn3

proc MoveToCheckColumn4
    jmp CheckColumn4
endp MoveToCheckColumn4

proc CheckColumn2
    cmp [SecondColumnArray], 0
    je ChangeColumn2Number1 
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 0
    je ChangeColumn2Number2 
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 0
    je ChangeColumn2Number3 
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 3], 0
    je ChangeColumn2Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
endp CheckColumn2

proc ChangeColumn2Number1
    inc [SecondColumnArray]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 87h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn2Number1

proc ChangeColumn2Number2
    inc [SecondColumnArray + 1]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn2Number2

proc ChangeColumn2Number3
    inc [SecondColumnArray + 2]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn2Number3

proc ChangeColumn2Number4
    inc [SecondColumnArray + 3]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 27h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn2Number4

proc CheckColumn3
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray], 0
    je ChangeColumn3Number1 
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 0
    je ChangeColumn3Number2 
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 0
    je ChangeColumn3Number3 
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 3], 0
    je ChangeColumn3Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
endp CheckColumn3

proc ChangeColumn3Number1
    inc [ThirdColumnArray]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 87h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn3Number1

proc ChangeColumn3Number2
    inc [ThirdColumnArray + 1]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn3Number2

proc ChangeColumn3Number3
    inc [ThirdColumnArray + 2]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn3Number3

proc ChangeColumn3Number4
    inc [ThirdColumnArray + 3]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 27h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn3Number4

proc CheckColumn4
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 0
    je ChangeColumn4Number1 
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 1], 0
    je ChangeColumn4Number2 
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 2], 0
    je ChangeColumn4Number3 
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 0
    je ChangeColumn4Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
endp CheckColumn4

proc ChangeColumn4Number1
    inc [FourthColumnArray]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 87h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn4Number1

proc ChangeColumn4Number2
    inc [FourthColumnArray + 1]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn4Number2

proc ChangeColumn4Number3
    inc [FourthColumnArray + 2]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn4Number3

proc ChangeColumn4Number4
    inc [FourthColumnArray + 3]
    mov [Player1Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player1Drawy], 27h
    jmp DrawPlayer1Disc
endp ChangeColumn4Number4

DrawPlayer1Loop:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[Player1Drawx]
    mov dx,[Player1Drawy]
    mov al,[player1disccolor]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [Player1Drawx]
    cmp cx, [Player1Drawx + 14h]
    jl DrawPlayer1Loop

DrawPlayer1Disc: 
    mov bh, 0h
    inc [Player1Drawy] 
    cmp dx, [Player1Drawy + 14h]
    jl DrawPlayer1Loop

proc GoToCheckIfPlayer1Won
    call CheckIfPlayer1Won
    jmp CheckPlayer2Number
endp GoToCheckIfPlayer1Won

proc CheckPlayer2Number
    mov ah, 7
    int 21h
    cmp al, 31h
    je Player2CheckColumn1
    cmp al, 32h
    je Player2CheckColumn2
    cmp al, 33h
    je MoveToCheck2Column3
    cmp al, 34h
    je MoveToCheck2Column4
    jmp CheckPlayer2Number
endp CheckPlayer2Number

proc Player2CheckColumn1
    cmp [FirstColumnArray], 0
    je Change2Column1Number1 
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 1], 0
    je Change2Column1Number2 
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 2], 0
    je Change2Column1Number3 
    cmp [FirstColumnArray + 3], 0
    je Change2Column1Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer2Number
endp Player2CheckColumn1

proc Change2Column1Number1
    add [FirstColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 87h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column1Number1

proc Change2Column1Number2
    add [FirstColumnArray + 1], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column1Number2

proc Change2Column1Number3
    add [FirstColumnArray + 2], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column1Number3

proc Change2Column1Number4
    add [FirstColumnArray + 3], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 25h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 27h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column1Number4

proc MoveToCheck2Column3
    jmp Player2CheckColumn3
endp MoveToCheck2Column3

proc MoveToCheck2Column4
    jmp Player2CheckColumn4
endp MoveToCheck2Column4    

proc Player2CheckColumn2
    cmp [SecondColumnArray], 0
    je Change2Column2Number1
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 1], 0
    je Change2Column2Number2
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 2], 0
    je Change2Column2Number3
    cmp [SecondColumnArray + 3], 0
    je Change2Column2Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer2Number
endp Player2CheckColumn2

proc Change2Column2Number1
    add [SecondColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 87h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column2Number1

proc Change2Column2Number2
    add [SecondColumnArray + 1], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column2Number2

proc Change2Column2Number3
    add [SecondColumnArray + 2], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column2Number3

proc Change2Column2Number4
    add [SecondColumnArray + 3], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 45h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column2Number4

proc Player2CheckColumn3
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray], 0
    je Change2Column3Number1
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 1], 0
    je Change2Column3Number2
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 2], 0
    je Change2Column3Number3
    cmp [ThirdColumnArray + 3], 0
    je Change2Column3Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer2Number
endp Player2CheckColumn3

proc Change2Column3Number1
    add [ThirdColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 87h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column3Number1

proc Change2Column3Number2
    add [ThirdColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column3Number2

proc Change2Column3Number3
    add [ThirdColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column3Number3

proc Change2Column3Number4
    add [ThirdColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 65h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 27h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column3Number4

proc Player2CheckColumn4
    cmp [FourthColumnArray], 0
    je Change2Column4Number1
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 1], 0
    je Change2Column4Number2
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 2], 0
    je Change2Column4Number3
    cmp [FourthColumnArray + 3], 0
    je Change2Column4Number4
    jmp CheckPlayer2Number  
endp Player2CheckColumn4

proc Change2Column4Number1
    add [FourthColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 87h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column4Number1

proc Change2Column4Number2
    add [FourthColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 67h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column4Number2

proc Change2Column4Number3
    add [FourthColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 47h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column4Number3

proc Change2Column4Number4
    add [FourthColumnArray], 2
    mov [Player2Drawx], 85h
    mov [Player2Drawy], 27h
    jmp DrawPlayer2Disc
endp Change2Column4Number4

DrawPlayer2Loop:
    mov bh,0h
    mov cx,[Player2Drawx]
    mov dx,[Player2Drawy]
    mov al,[player2disccolor]
    mov ah,0ch
    int 10h
    inc [Player2Drawx]
    cmp cx, [Player2Drawx + 14h]
    jl DrawPlayer2Loop

DrawPlayer2Disc: 
    mov bh, 0h
    inc [Player2Drawy]
    cmp dx, [Player2Drawy + 14h]
    jl DrawPlayer2Loop

proc GoToCheckIfPlayer2Won
    call CheckIfPlayer2Won
    jmp CheckPlayer1Number
endp GoToCheckIfPlayer2Won

next:
    ; Wait for key press
     mov ah,00h
     int 16h
    ; Return to text mode
    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 2
    int 10h

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Explanation for my code: 
A player has to choose a number between 1-4. When he pressed one of the numbers, it checks which number he pressed and sends it to column procedures which are supposed to check if there are any "open" spaces to draw a disc on the board. I am suspecting that the problem is maybe located somewhere in the drawing part because it obviously doesn't stop and it makes the program crash.

This is a long read so thanks for the patience and help.

Comment: Post the full code (yes, the 1178 lines), I want to run it here. Or, more info is required : what are the values for Player1Drawx and y? How is the "disc" suppose to look? Suggestion : there are some funny ASCII chars that you can use instead of a "disc" to represent the user on screen : ☺☻♥♦♣♠•◘○◙♂♀♪♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼

Comment: Thanks for the help, I willpost the code later. The disc is a squre, I didnt't want to do anything too complicated with my project. The values are set to 0.

Comment: ASCII char 254 is a square ■, 219 is a rectangle █, you can replace your graphic square by some of those. For example, two 219 make a big square : █+█ = ██ .

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I uploaded the code. Thanks for the tips but I have this project due on Sunday and I prefer to not change things, just to make it work. In my free time I will try to improve it, after my finals.

Comment: The error is on line 953, DX has not the proper value (`cmp dx, [Player1Drawy + 14h]`). Not sure what value DX should have.

Answer (score 1):

I modified some routines, and now it works!
I have the feeling that you are no more interested in 2018.

Anyway... the first bug is here:
cmp cx, [Player1Drawx + 14h]
you tried to see that cx has incremented 14h times, the addressing is wrong.